# SQLITE_NOTADB error with Xerial's JDBC SQLite on Mac OSX Mavericks (10.9.1)

Tags: java, macos, sqlite, jdbc

I'm having the following error while reading a SQLite database from JDBC: `[SQLITE_NOTADB]  File opened that is not a database file (file is encrypted or is not a database)`. As far I can tell this database is not encrypted (see headers below) and sqlite3 is able to execute the same command without any error or warning.

Any suggestion/idea to fix this issue ?

**Source code**

```
package foo;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        String fn = "/Users/jerome/db.sql";
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + fn);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeQuery("SELECT 1 FROM sqlite_master");
    }
}
```

**How to run**

```
java -cp /Users/jerome/.m2/repository/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.7.2/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar:foo.jar foo.Test
```

**Stacktrace**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_NOTADB]  File opened that is not a database file (file is encrypted or is not a database)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:383)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:387)
    at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:374)
    at org.sqlite.NestedDB.prepare(NestedDB.java:134)
    at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:123)
    at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeQuery(Stmt.java:121)
    at foo.Test.main(Test.java:16)
```

**With sqlite3**

```
sqlite3 ~/Desktop/db.sql "SELECT 1 FROM sqlite_master"
1
1
[...]
1
```

**DB Header**

```
hexdump -C ~/Desktop/db.sql | head
00000000  53 51 4c 69 74 65 20 66  6f 72 6d 61 74 20 33 00  |SQLite format 3.|
00000010  10 00 02 02 00 40 20 20  00 00 2e 0b 00 00 01 7c  |.....@  .......||
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 21 00 00 00 04  |...........!....|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 24  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00  |.......$........|
00000040  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 2e 0b  |................|
00000060  00 2d e2 25 05 00 00 00  01 0f fb 00 00 00 00 25  |.-.%...........%|
00000070  0f fb 04 bf 04 20 03 78  02 cd 02 22 01 92 00 f9  |..... .x..."....|
00000080  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a compatibility issue with 3.7.2. The problem disappear when I switched to 3.7.15-M1. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and the reason for this was, that I opened my new SQLite Database(sqlite-jdbc Version: 3.21.0.1)  with the old
"**SQLite Administrator** (Version: 0.8.3.2 Public Beta), Year: 2013". 
All SQL statements worked without any problems, but after saving, it was not possible to connect to the database (via JDBC) any more.

Therefore I changed the DB Programm to "**DB Browser for SQLite 3.9.1**, Year 2017",  and everything functioned again!

This took time and much effort, because I didn't think about it ... but perhaps I could help somebody to save some time with my solution :-)